# Rails 3 project, installed jquery-rails gem, but getting "Ajax is not defined"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm a rails newbie trying to follow a howto on how to perform some Ajax calls (after switching to jQuery), but I've run into a problem.

Whenever I trigger the ajax code (`new Ajax.Request()`), I get "Ajax is not defined" in firebug. Anyone with more skills than me know what's up here?

**update:**

For anyone else having this problem, the code that was generating the the above code, was a call to `remote_function()`

---

What I have done to set things up:

1. Added "gem 'jquery-rails', '>= 1.0.12'" to my gemfile, and run bundle install
2. Run rails generate jquery:install

My public/javascripts/ folder thus has the following files:

- application.js
- jquery.min.js
- jquery-ui.min.js
- jquery.js
- jquery-ui.js
- jquery_ujs.js

The scripts included in my HTML look like this:

```
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.js?1312911234" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery-ui.js?1312911234" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery_ujs.js?1312911234" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/application.js?1312911234" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd guess that your tutorial uses Prototype as [`Ajax.Request`](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/ajax/request) is for Prototype, you should be using [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) with jQuery. And switching to a jQuery based tutorial might be a good idea too.

You say that you're using [`remote_function`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper.html#method-i-remote_function) but that's [Prototype-specific](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper.html):

> **Usage**
>   To be able to use these helpers, you must first include the Prototype JavaScript framework in your pages.

Prototype used to be the default JavaScript library for Rails so I suspect that PrototypeHelper is a leftover. You probably want to look at things like the `:remote` option on [`link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) and similar for new code.

Comment: Hmm, ok. I thought perhaps the helpers would make some of it transparent. For example, the code generating the Ajax call is a call to remote_function(). I can't expect stuff like that to work after I switched to jQuery?